# Pulling client Side username ASP Classics

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, intranet

We have this intranet site on the office in which it has 'post for ideas' module. Everyone is free to post anything they want and put any kind of name they want. So, after reviewing it, my boss required me to create a code snippet to check for their respective windows username and save it with the post.

I just need to pull the client username using the local intranet. The intranet doesn't have a login feature and that makes it little bit harder.

I have used this following codes

```vb
<%
Dim objNet
Set objNet = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Response.Write("WScript.NetWork.UserName is " + objNet.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%") + "<br>")
Response.Write("WScript.NetWork.UserDomain is " + objNet.UserDomain + "<br>")
Response.Write("WScript.NetWork.ComputerName is " + objNet.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%ComputerName%") + "<p>")
%>
```

the code about is returning the server informations such as comp name, ip and username

```vb
var wshell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
WScript.Echo(wshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERNAME%"));
```

the code about is returning nothing but when i change my IE setting to IE 9, it debugs and said server cannot create activexobject.

im using asp classic for the intranet were created using that.

Comment: You can use `Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")` or `Request.ServerVariables("AUTH_USER")` but you'll need to ensure that the authentication mode in IIS is set to Windows. If you're looking for an IP address then try `Request.ServerVariables("LOCAL_ADDR ")`.

Comment: @Paul is absolutely right - Here is a [good article from 4guysfromrolla](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092298-3.shtml) that breaks it down for you.

Comment: @Paul when I was learning Classic ASP *(about 15 years ago)* those 4Guy were the best resource out there and still are *(timeless)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see Paul & Lankymart between them have already answered in the comments, but I'll go ahead and post an answer anyway.

To get the logged-in username, use `Request.ServerVariables("LOGON_USER")`. The authentication mode in IIS does need to be set to Windows, but if this is an intranet, it might already be set correctly. (Note that ServerVariables isn't particularly efficient, so try to only call it only once. If you need the login information in multiple places, set a session variable.)

Calling a WScript shell from asp probably isn't going to work: the shell would need to be opened on the server, and no sane server admin is going to set the permissions to allow that.